# how do I add a if clause, like if (certain condition), then add a .addField?

Tags: discord, discord.js

how do I add a if clause, like if (certain condition), then add a .addField?

```
let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       //.addField('**Description**', )
       .setTitle(`**Command name :** ${name}`)
       .addField('**Description**', `${command.description}`)
       .addField('**Aliases**', `${command.aliases.join(', ')}`)
       .addField('**Usage**', `${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`)
       .addField('**Cooldown**', `${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`)
       .setColor('RANDOM')
       message.channel.send(embed2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
if (condition) embed2.addField('Title', 'Text');
```